# Proof of Yoneda's lemma on wikipedia.

Tags: proof-writing, category-theory, functors, yoneda-lemma

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoneda_lemma#Proof

The part I'm not getting is the last one:

> Moreover, any element ${\displaystyle u\in F(A)}$ defines a natural transformation in this way.

So we want to determine a natural transformation by $u \in F(A)$ and the obvious choice is to define $\alpha_X(g) = (Fg)u$ where $u =: \alpha_A(\text{id}_A)$ is defined that way.

To prove naturality we need to show that $(Fg) \alpha_X = \alpha_Y \text{Hom}(A, g)$ or that $F(g)\alpha_X(\xi) = \alpha_Y g (\xi)$ for all $\xi \in \text{Hom}(X, X)$, but we have by our above definitions:

$$
F(g) \alpha_X(\xi) = \alpha_Y \circ g \circ \xi = (F g) \alpha_A(\text{id}_A)
$$

I think I messed up somewhere.  What is the most concise 1 to 3 line proof using the above not-so-well developed vernacular?

I'm in the process of designing how BananaCats would help the user prove Yoneda, and the diagram on the wiki page is perfect.  Now, if I could only understand it, then I could write better software, perhaps.

By the way, I'm on the 3rd rewrite of BananaCats.  Drag-and-drop works which has the natural side effect of copy / paste.  Undo redo works beautifully and...

the undo/redo stack saves to file!  So when you restart your computer (or something) you can go  back to what you were working on and still undo old changes!  $F$ yeah!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be for any $u \in F(A)$ define $\alpha(u)_X(f: A \to X) = (Ff)(u)$ and so for any $g : Z \to Y$ in $C$ we have to prove $\alpha_Y \circ \text{Hom}(A, g) = F(g) \circ \alpha_Z$ on all inputs $\xi \in \text{Hom}(A, Z)$.  But the goal equation expands to:

$$
\alpha_Y \circ g \circ \xi = (Fg) \circ \alpha_Z(\xi) = (Fg)\circ(F\xi)(u) = F(g)\circ F(\xi) (u) = \\ F(g\circ \xi) (u) = \alpha_Y \circ(g \circ \xi) = \alpha_Y \circ g \circ \xi
$$

Amazing!  I love proving Yoneda.